# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Homebrewing Stack Exchange](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Using 5L oak barrel for beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12686/using-5l-oak-barrel-for-beer)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Forgot to add whirfloc / irish moss to wort during boil](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12665/forgot-to-add-whirfloc-irish-moss-to-wort-during-boil)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Raspberry Stout Contamination('infection')?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12677/raspberry-stout-infection)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Airlock started bubbling after racking into secondary and dryhopping, why?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/airlock-started-bubbling-after-racking-into-secondary-and-dryhopping-why)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Which Stores carry the metal connectors for constructing a Mash Tun?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12714/which-stores-carry-the-metal-connectors-for-constructing-a-mash-tun)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I extend my kegerator beer line run properly?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/how-do-i-extend-my-kegerator-beer-line-run-properly)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Modifying Recipes for Boil Volume](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12758/modifying-recipes-for-boil-volume)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [My pressure barrel stopped pouring even though 3/4 full](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12692/my-pressure-barrel-stopped-pouring-even-though-3-4-full)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Push fit auto close valve connector required](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12701/push-fit-auto-close-valve-connector-required)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How add authentic coconut flavor to a fermeted beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12752/how-add-authentic-coconut-flavor-to-a-fermeted-beer)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---